# How to easily initialize array with old array indices?

Tags: python

I am trying to do a large scale of something like this on python:

```
old_array = [5 4 2 3]
new_array = [old_array[2] old_array[1] old_array[0] old_array[3]]
```

but that last line of code syntax says it's wrong. How do I do this simply, being that I have 100 elements that I want to copy to another array OUT OF ORDER.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp

Comment: Do you need to randomly shuffle the elements or is there a specific order you need to apply?  BTW your example has an invalid index on `old_array[4]`

Comment: There's a specific order, that's just the example I did as if that was the specific order. Thanks, fixed it.

Comment: `new_array = [old_array[i] for i in (2,1,0,3)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put commas between your list elements:

```
old_array = [5, 4, 2, 3]
new_array = [old_array[2], old_array[1], old_array[0], old_array[3]]

print(new_array)
```

Comment: Really dumb mistake...Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension to generalize the indirection:

```
old_array = [5,4,2,3]
new_order = [2,1,0,3]

new_array = [old_array[i] for i in new_order]
```